# How do I align an h3 with a p without creating two separate lines?

Tags: html, css

I have html code that looks like this:

```
<h3>Corruption, the most infallible symptom of constitutional liberty.</h3>
<p>~ Edward Gibbon</p>
```

The resulting output is below:

[image]

As I pointed out w/ the arrow, I don't want Edward Gibbon below the quote, but preferably to the right of "liberty".

Is this possible, if I have h3 tags involved?  Should I be using span or div tags?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Updated solution in case anybody needs this in the future (via Greg Jennings):**

```
<h3>Corruption, the most infallible symptom of constitutional liberty. <span 
class="parastyled" style="font-size: 10px;">~ Edward Gibbon</span></h3>
```

The resulting output is below:

[image]

Comment: where does the `parastyled` class come from?

Comment: I have no idea, Eru ... I just copied what Greg put in there, and things worked as shown above.

Comment: ahh in that case, I believe that `class="parasyled"` is unnecisary, it works because you put it in a `span` inside the h3

Comment: thanks for responding to each of us by the way, much apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a span inside the  tag with the style you want. You need an inline element here.

```
<h3>Corruption, the most infallible symptom of constitutional liberty. <span class="parastyled">~ Edward Gibbon</span></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks Greg -- for the solution (it worked) and for teaching me a new class I've never heard of -- "parastyled".  I'll have to add that to my CSS learning database, which is about 2000 mb and growing.  Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Just so you know under normal cases you'll actually need to specify the style for that class in your CSS. It just happened to work out in this case because in your CSS your span tag had styles similar to a p tag. The "parastyled" class is just a hook to allow you to specify the style on that element. It doesn't do anything by itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Just make them inline!

```
h3, p{ 
    display: inline;
}
```

Note, you probably don't want this to affect all p's and h2's so i'd do this:

```
<div class="same-line">
    <h2>blah balh</h2>
    <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.same-line p, .same-line h2{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't that create some adverse effects on the rest of the page?

Comment: Thanks Eru.  I used Greg's solution and that worked.  But I did test your solution and that worked as well.  Thanks, because it's nice to have another solution to fall back upon.  Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the display type of the p and h3 tags

HTML:

```
<h3 class="sameline">Corruption, the most infallible symptom of constitutional liberty.</h3>
<p class="sameline">~ Edward Gibbon</p>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .sameline {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: inline-block won't quite work here because the h2 takes multiple lines.

Comment: Toan, you still have inline block, this will work if the title is under one line, but if the title is two lines it will reserve a square block and the p will go on a new line

Comment: Eru, Toan's solution didn't work for me, gut Greg's solution (below) did the trick.  Thank you for taking the time to respond, Toan!

Comment: @JasonWeber You're welcome. I have updated the answer to make the elements inline

Answer (score 2):

You should use the correct tools for the job.

This is a quote, it belongs in a `blockquote`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2a2S9/

HTML:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>Corruption, the most infallible symptom of constitutional liberty.</p>
    <p class="byline">~ Edward Gibbon</p>
</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
blockquote { font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; }

blockquote p { display: inline-block; }

blockquote p.byline { font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px; }
```

Comment: change inline:block to inline and it will work with multi-line quotes. updated your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6gv56/1/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make the fiddles, Setek, Eru.  I just used the parastyled class for now, but these solutions work as well -- and Eru's solution in a separate answer gave pretty much the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

`<h3>` is a block element, it will use all the available width. You could use a `span` inside the `h3` instead of the `p`. Or you could replace the `h3` with an `inline` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {

 display:inline;
 float:none;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following css

```
h3,p{ 
    float:left;
    width:auto;
}
```